# Meaning of ERROR 001707 when sharing layer as layer package file from ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-pro, layer-package

I have had no success when trying to share a layer as a layer package file from ArcGIS Pro 1.2.

The procedure that I use to reproduce this is:

1. Start ArcGIS Pro 1.2
2. Create a New Project using the Map.aptx template and call it Test.  I placed mine in a folder called C:\polygeo (which already exists)
3. In the Project pane add a folder connection to C:\polygeo where I have a point shapefile called ne_10m_populated_places.shp that is from Natural Earth
4. Drag and drop that shapefile into the Map
5. Open the Layer Properties for that new layer and use the Metadata tab to set its Description to Test Description (and then OK to close the Layer Properties)
6. Right-click on the layer to choose Share As Layer Package
7. On the Share As A Layer Package dialog:

   - set **Save package to file** (as an aside, the option to Upload package to Online account seems to work)
   - set Name & Location to **C:\polygeo\ne_10m_populated_places.lpkx**
   - set Summary to **Test Summary**
   - set Tags to **test-tag**
   - click **Analyze** (there should be no errors or warnings)
   - click **Package**
8. Expect to see:

> ERROR 001707: Data cannot be opened: Shape
>   File(C:\polygeo\ne_10m_populated_places) ne_10m_populated_places.shp

I have not been able to find any documentation on ArcGIS Pro ERROR 001707.

Does anyone know what may be causing it?

For anyone trying to reproduce this error the ne_10m_populated_places.shp can be downloaded from http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked with the team and it appears the error in question is one that had to "change addresses" as there was a conflict in the error number.  That led to it being undocumented in the current release - the team will work to mitigate that doc error in the next release of Pro.

Something is causing the layer to fail to be accessed during the consolidation process.  If you can send this data or a link to it into Esri support, the team can try the repro case and get it assigned to the correct gp team member.

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to be specific to layers with shapefiles as their source.

When I copied the shapefile into the project's geodatabase as a feature class, and added that as a layer to my map, the Sharing As A Layer Package process was able to create a layer package file as expected.